# C++ templated class "no appropriate default constructor available"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, template-classes

I created a Node class for a linked list in C++:

```
template <class T> class Node {
public:
    T val;
    Node* next;
    Node(T val) {
        this->val = val;
        this->next = nullptr;
    }
    ~Node() {
        Node<T>* temp = this->next;
        if (temp != nullptr && temp->next != nullptr)
            delete(temp->next);
    }
};
```

And when trying tp initialize it:

```
definition: 
Node<Device>* devices;
code (in function):
this->devices = new Node<Device>({ this->serial_counter, name });
```

I get this error:

> Error C2512   'Device': no appropriate default constructor
>   available Gym c:\users\amitm\onedrive\מסמכים\visual studio
>   2015\projects\gym\gym\node.h  7

Line 7:

```
Node(T val) {
```

Also, if needed, this is the "Device" constructor:

```
Device::Device(int id, char* name) {
    this->id = id;
    strcpy(this->name, name);
}
```

How can I fix this error? I looked on-line for over an hour and cannot find a solution that works for me.

Comment: Have you tried coding in a default constructor maybe? Might do magics.

Comment: I did now, and it worked, but this i do want to construct it with data. an empty constructor won't be exactly what I need.

Comment: You don't need to write linked-list classes in C++. Use `std::list`.

Comment: I know I have the std::list, but this is an excercise from Uni, and this is the requirement. (and if I go and see how std::list is implemented, I will pretty much copy it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your value of type `T` is initialized in your constructor, and you then try to assign a new value. If you want to remove the error message, you need to initialize your value yourself:

```
Node(T v)
: val(v)
, next(nullptr)
{}
```

You can have more information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).